# Tengo un codigo para hacer un Contador de espacios en blanco, letras y números con while. Tenia la idea de como se podria hacer pero al final no salio

Tags: python, while

"""
Se que puede que todo este mal, tenia la idea de como se podia hacer pero al final quede
bloqueado
"""

```
input("Ingrese un mensaje: ")
msg = ""
caracteres = 0
digitos = 0
espaciosenblanco = 0
while True:
s = input ()
msg += "(0:s)\n",format(s)

largocadena = len(s)
j = 0
while j < largocadena:
    
    j = j + 1

 print("[0:d] [0:d] [0:d]", format(caracteres, digitos, espaciosenblanco))
```

Comment: ¿Y la pregunta sería ... ?

Comment: ¿Como seria el codigo para hacer que el programa me de un contador de espacios, de letras y de numeros? por medio de una entrada estandar.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando **bucle for**

```
str = input("Ingrese un mensaje: ")
caracteres = 0
digitos = 0
espaciosenblanco = 0

for char in str:
    if (char.isalpha()):
        caracteres += 1
    elif char.isdigit():
        digitos += 1
    elif (char==" "):
        espaciosenblanco += 1

print ("Caracteres = ", caracteres,"\nDigitos = ",digitos,"\nEspacios en blanco = ",espaciosenblanco)
```

Donde `str` = Input del usuario.

Aquí hacemos un bucle `for` sobre `str` recorriendo de esta forma cada uno de los caracteres del string hasta que finaliza.

Comprobamos carácter por caracter (`char` dentro del bucle) si es una letra `.isalpha`, si es un digito `.isdigit()` o bien si es igual a un espacio en blanco `char == " "`. Cuando estos casos se cumplen se les suma `1` a las variables correspondientes según el caso.

Al final, hacemos un print con los resultados de los variables donde ya aplicas el formato que tu deseas.

Utilizando **bucle while**.

```
str = input("Ingrese un mensaje: ")
caracteres = 0
digitos = 0
espaciosenblanco = 0

count = 0
while count < len(str):
    if (str[count].isalpha()):
        caracteres += 1
    elif (str[count].isdigit():
        digitos += 1
    elif (str[count]==" "):
        espaciosenblanco += 1
    count+=1

print ("Caracteres = ", caracteres,"\nDigitos = ",digitos,"\nEspacios en blanco = ",espaciosenblanco
```

Inicializamos la variable `count = 0` que utilizamos como contador.

En nuestro bucle `while` decimos que mientras `count` es menor que la longitud del string siga el bucle.

Utilizamos `str[count]` para comprobar cada letra del string ya que es como hacer `str[0] , str[1]` hasta que finaliza el string y lo utilizamos en los condicionales para comprobar si son letras, digitos o espacios en blanco.

Al final del bucle aumentamos el valor de count por 1 para saltar de índice y comprobar el siguiente caracter

Comment: Cualquier duda, aclaración o sugerencia por parte de otro usuario, escribir un comentario! Un saludo.

Comment: Lo tendras con un ciclo while?

Comment: Porqué motivo quieres hacerlo con un `while`? Y si, ahora actualizo la respuesta

Comment: @Shon Casper ya tienes la respuesta actualizada utilizando un `while`. Un saludo! Espero un comentario tuyo!

Comment: Nah que grande!!!!. La razon de por que lo quiero con while es por que asi me lo pidieron. Pero gracias compañero por esta gran ayuda. Saludos!!!

Comment: Recuerda que no es recomendable declarar variables que se llamen igual que algo built-in de Python. En este caso str.

Comment: Al final de todo trat de hacer una conversión a string, por ejemplo `str(9)` y verás el lindo error :)